# Tracing Rails configuration changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

An application has a `config.action_view.cache_template_loading = true` in `production.rb` but during rendering of the template the setting is `nil`. How can I trace where it was changed? (Obviously, there are no other mentions of `cache_template_loading` in project code, it's changed by some external dependency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've set the value to what you want, you can leave a booby-trap that explodes when anyone else tries to set the value:

```
config.action_view.cache_template_loading = true

def (config.action_view).cache_template_loading=(new_value)
  raise RunTimeError, "Someone reconfigured cache_template-loading"
end
```

You'll get a stack trace showing exactly where the value is set.

(Obviously, this is a diagnostic tool for running locally and not suitable for actually committing to the code base.)

Comment: Thanks. This exact code doesn't work though, I used `class << config.action_view`

Comment: I've fixed it now, but I'm glad it was helpful even if the original code didn't run exactly.